# Apply c# dictionary output to html table

Tags: c#, html, dictionary, code-behind

I have a dictionary with string and int and I would like to parse the dictionary string and ints to a html table if that is possible?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Dictionary<string, int> userMediaList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        userMediaList.Add("Die Hard", 5);
        userMediaList.Add("Die Hard II", 3);
        userMediaList.Add("Die Hard III", 2);
        userMediaList.Add("Ringenes Herre", 4);
        userMediaList.Add("Ringenes Herre II", 1);
        userMediaList.Add("Ringenes Herre III", 5);

        var sortUserMediaList = from entry in userMediaList orderby entry.Value ascending select entry;

    }
```

So what i want is adding this to a table on the website.

So that for every box in the table, the name of the movie and the rating of the movie will appear.

Comment: Of course it's possible. It depends on the technologies you're using...

Comment: Geez Andrei V. whats up with the hate.... @Winkz, you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274875/bind-dictionary-to-repeater , they bind a dictionnary to a repeater. that could easily do exactly what you want.

Comment: Is it in a web application?

Comment: Okay thats good i guess :D well atm im looping through the entries with a foreach loop.. just dont know how to apply each line to a new "box" in the table.

Comment: Thank you Dave, gonna try and read that! Ufuk it's a webpage, so yea i suppose :)

Comment: @Winkz, not really intentional. But was I not answering the question? Although grammar "enthusiasts" would agree that (at least in the first sentence) the "question" is not really a question...

Comment: Ill edit it then i guess if you are picky about it ;p

Comment: @Dave I had a look at it and cant really figure out, how that would help me.. Totally new at parsing things from code behind :/

Answer (score 6):

As you don't state what technology you are using, this is a generic way:

```
var trs = dictionary.Select(a => String.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", a.Key, a.Value));

var tableContents = String.Concat(trs);

var table = "<table>" + tableContents + "</table>";
```

Comment: Nothing comes up from adding this to the code :/ Do i need to add something in the html part?

Comment: Well you need to render it somehow. You've not really given enough information for people to help you properly I'm afraid.

Comment: Gonna edit the mainpost again i guess :p

Answer (score 2):

You can start with that, but there are probably better methods:

```
string html = "<table>";
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> pair in userMediaList)
    {
        html = html + String.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", pair.Key, pair.Value.ToString());
    }
html = html + "</table>";
```

Comment: Nothing comes up from adding this to the code :/ Do i need to add something in the html part?