# How to Bind IDictionary to Repeater different controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, repeater

I have an `IDictionary` object:

```cs
IDictionary<int, string> keyPair = new Dictionary<int, string>();
keyPair.Add(1, "value1");
keyPair.Add(2, "value2");
keyPair.Add(3, "value3");
keyPair.Add(4, "value4");
```

And I have HTML code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to bind value where key=1 inside td1 and key=2 inside td2 and so

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind dictionary to repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274875/bind-dictionary-to-repeater)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-First :In you Controller make sure to add your dictionary in a viewbag :

```
            ViewBag.keyPair = keyPair;
```

-Then in your cshtml page add :

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>@ViewBag.keyPair[1]</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.keyPair[2]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@ViewBag.keyPair[3]</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.keyPair[4]</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```